# How to restart X server with the old key combination (ctrl -alt - backspace) in 14.04

Tags: xorg, 14.04, shortcut-keys

I know that since 11.04 the keyboard short-cut of **Ctrl+Alt+Backspace** has been disabled by default.  However at least as recently as 12.04 you were able to enable it via the Keyboard GUI:

[image]

The Keyboard options in 14.04 are much more limited and there appears to be no way to re-enable this function:

[image]

Is there any way to re-enable this function?  All my searches of AU as well as a full internet search have provided no workable answers for 14.04.